# How do I 'query' JSON object with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am working on Jquery Autocomplete and due to internet poor connection, I have to load my whole list(I mean Json object) on page load itself.Now my question is how do I query on that Json object so my autocomplete get a filter as user start typing keyword in a textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#InsuranceCompanyDisplayName").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var data = $('#InsuranceCompanyjson').text();
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    value: item.InsuranceCompanyDisplay,
                    id: item.InsuranceCompanyId
                }
            }))
        },

    });

});
```

Here (var data = $('#InsuranceCompanyjson').text();) I get my list from Html page and passes to Jquery Autocomplete. I know on request object I will get term to get user input but how do I use that input and query that Json object as we do in the database using LIKE Keyword.

Comment: Are you looking for jQuery specifically?

Comment: yes, but If some other option available then I would like to know. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you store properly formatted JSON in `#InsuranceCompanyjson` element as text, you need to parse it back to JS object before using in javascript:

```
var data = JSON.parse($('#InsuranceCompanyjson').text());
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and also verify my Json string but still, it's not working.

Comment: I tried to alert on var data =JSON.parse($('#InsuranceCompanyjson').text()); but after alert my function stop working and in alert I am getting right josn output,

Comment: It's  " Invalid 'in' operand obj "

Comment: I solved that issue but still, I want to filter that option based on user input as I describe in my question using request.term I will get user input and then I want to filter my list based on that. To solve above issue we have to make one step more in your answer  which is                           var Jstring = eval('(' + $('#InsuranceCompanyjson').text() + ')');
var data = JSON.parse(Jstring);

Comment: If you need to make eval step (which is bad idea) it means that you didn't provide proper JSON in the first place. Write JSON into #InsuranceCompanyjson and you will not need extra step. In any case instead of eval, use two JSON.parse.